# C# - Is there a 32-bit float math library?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point

I'm planning on doing my next project in c# rather than c++ (using SlimDX).

All of directX uses floats, however System.Math uses doubles. This means constantly converting between floats and doubles.

So ideally I'd like to write all the code using floats, since I'm not getting any added precision converting to floats from doubles all the time anyways...

However Ive been unable to find a set of maths functions for .net that uses floats. I could of course write my own library in c#, but id rather use an existing library which has been optimised etc...

Comment: There is an issue on github requesting just this for corelcr:[https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1151](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1151).

Answer (score 2):

XNA provides several math constants (including 3D specialists, like PI/2 etc.) and some advanced math functions with float precision (though not the trigonometric functions). While that is most likely not an option for you, since XNA is not as slim as SlimDX, it certainly means that System.Math is either actually missing something, or the performance hit is not that big. In my experience, you don't actually calculate that much for yourself, because most of that is handled either by the geometry classes (Matrix, Quaternion, Vector) or the GPU itself.

From that point of view, I'd have a look into SlimDX, what they are providing. Seems like the typical things like matrices, vectors, quaternions (and even 16 bit floats) are already there. If you're missing some constants with float precisions, just create them yourself (don't have the cast to be done every time, just at startup).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll make very significant performance gains by working end-to-end in floats if that is all the precision that is required.

Check out the [NMath](http://centerspace.net) libraries from CenterSpace software.  Float, double, and complex types are consistently supported throughout the library.

Paul

Comment: While the cost of conversions is non-trivial, the performance gains are significantly dependent on how often he is doing the operations. I have been using the System.Math version of Sin/Cos etc, but I only use them a handful of times per camera movement, meaning I wouldn't gain even a frame a second from changing libraries. However if you are doing hardcore float operations as your primary workload (for instance procedural terrain generation on the CPU) it is a good idea to do them with such a library.

Answer (score 1):

Answer on question in title: **Yes**.

Starting with **.NET Core 2.0 (.NET Standard 2.1)** you can use built-in `MathF` class to work with float types to perform mathematic operations.

See [docs about `MathF` type on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.mathf)